# GridGain server deployment/Statefulset Termination grace period

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ignite, gridgain

I deployed gridgain cluster in google kubernetes cluster following[1]. I enabled native persistency using statefulset. In statefulset.yaml in [2] **terminationGracePeriodSeconds** set to **60000**. What is the purpose of this large timeout?

When deleting pod using **kubectl delete pod** command it take very large time. What is the suitable value for **terminationGracePeriodSeconds** without loss any data.

[1]. https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/kubernetes/gke-deployment

[2]. https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/kubernetes/gke-deployment#creating-pod-configuration

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason behind setting it to 60000 was - do not rely on it. Prior to Ignite 2.9 there was an issue with the startup script that didn't bypass SYS SIGNAL to the underlying Java app, making it impossible to perform a graceful shutdown.

If a node is being restarted gracefully and [IGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/starting-nodes#preventing-partition-loss-on-shutdown) is enabled, Ignite will ensure that the node leave won't lead to a data loss. Sometimes a rebalance might take a while.

Keeping the above in mind: the hang issue might happen for Apache Ignite 2.8 and below, keeping the recommended terminationGracePeriodSeconds should be fine and never be used in practice (in a normal flow).